# Nightbot command

Tags: command, twitch

I don't know if I'm posting to the right place or what but I was wondering if someone could help me with a **Nightbot** command I want to make.
I have the !uptime command and I have a !rage command which only retrieves one value. Now I'd like to combine the two into a command that would retrieve 5 or 6 different values (stages of rage in this situation) depending on what value !uptime would retrieve. So basically if I have been streaming for an hour !rage would say minimum but if for 5 hours it would say critical or something.

How is this possible? Someone pls help

Answer (score 0):

### TL:DR; the Final Command

You can use this to achieve what you want (the messages are used as an example, customize as you wish):

```js
@$(channel) is $(eval let messages=["a-ok","irritated","wrathful","furious","in a fit of rage"],hrs=(Date.now()-new Date("$(twitch $(channel) "{{uptimeAt}}")").getTime())/3600000,toIndex=(d,l,u,c)=>d<l?0:d>=u?c-1:Math.floor((c-2)*(d-l)/(u-l))+1;messages[toIndex(hrs,1,5,5)])
```

It produces the following messages:

```
@streamer is a-ok               (during the first hour)
@streamer is irritated          (during the second hour)
@streamer is wrathful           (during the third hour)
@streamer is furious            (during the fourth hour)
@streamer is in a fit of rage   (after the start of the fifth hour)
```

You can tweak the start and end of these "stages of rage" by changing the numbers in `toIndex(hrs,1,5,5)`. The second number is how many hours (can be a decimal) you are normal/a-ok. The third number is how many hours (also can be a decimal) until you are fully tilted. The last number is how many "stages of rage" you are using (must be a whole number and should match the length of `messages`).

By tweaking this, you could have spread out enough messages over a 24-hour stream to indicate how tired you are among other things.

---

### Command Breakdown

#### Variables

Nightbot supports a [number of variables](https://docs.nightbot.tv/commands/variableslist) you can use in your commands. To achieve what you want, you will need the following variables:

- `$(command)` is replaced with the channel's username. ([docs](https://docs.nightbot.tv/variables/channel))
- `$(twitch $(channel))` is replaced with information about this Twitch channel (follow count, uptime, etc) ([docs](https://docs.nightbot.tv/variables/twitch)) - we'll be using it to get the stream uptime.
- `$(eval javascript)` is replaced with the result of the given JavaScript code. ([docs](https://docs.nightbot.tv/variables/eval))

#### How they are used

To get the start time of your stream, you can use `uptimeAt` with `$(twitch)`:

```
$(twitch $(channel) "{{uptimeAt}}") --> "Mon Dec 07 2015 22:10:56 GMT-0500 (EST)"
```

You can convert this to hours streamed by converting it to a JavaScript `Date` object and then back to a numerical time using:

```js
@$(channel) has been live for $(eval let hoursStreamed = (Date.now() - new Date("$(twitch $(channel) "{{uptimeAt}}")").getTime())/3600000; Math.round(hoursStreamed * 10) / 10) hours.
```

Next, we need to define the "levels of rage":

```js
@$(channel) is $(eval let messages = ["a-ok", "irritated", "wrathful", "furious", "in a fit of rage"]; messages[0]).
```

Once we have the number of hours streamed, we need to convert it into an index that we can use to select a message.

In this part, I use a number of variables to calculate the appropriate index, this is what they mean:

- `duration`: the number of hours the stream has been running
- `lowerBound`: the minimum duration before the rage level increases past the default entry
- `upperBound`: the maximum duration before the rage level reaches the most extreme entry
- `entryCount`: the number of entries that can be selected

```js
// converts the given duration value into an index for an array of size entryCount
function toIndex(duration, lowerBound, upperBound, entryCount) {
  if (duration < lowerBound) {
    // default rage level
    return 0;
  }

  if (duration >= upperBound) {
    // maximum rage level
    return entryCount - 1; // the last valid index
  }

  // the progress between the lowerBound and upperBound
  // progress will be a float between 0 and 1
  const progress = (duration - lowerBound) / (upperBound - lowerBound);

  // this is the number of entries to be spread out between the bounds
  const entriesBetweenBounds = entryCount - 2;

  // map progress to an index
  return Math.floor(progress * entriesBetweenBounds) + 1;
}
```

Using a ternary operator, this can be compressed down to:

```js
function toIndex(duration, lowerBound, upperBound, entryCount) {
  return duration < lowerBound ? 0 : (
    duration >= upperBound ? entryCount - 1 : (
      Math.floor((entryCount - 2) * (duration - lowerBound)/(upperBound - lowerBound)) + 1
    )
  );
}
```

and can be minified down to:

```js
let toIndex=(d,l,u,c)=>d<l?0:d>=u?c-1:Math.floor((c-2)*(d-l)/(u-l))+1;
```

To use `toIndex` with the hours streamed, where you are normal up to 1 hr after starting, are majorly tilted at 5 hours, and have 5 stages of anger, you would use:

```js
toIndex(hoursStreamed, 1 /* hours you are normal */, 5 /* hours until full-tilt */, 5 /* number of rage stages */)
```

You can then bring it all together like so:

```js
@$(channel) is $(eval
  let messages=["a-ok","irritated","wrathful","furious","in a fit of rage"],
  hrs=(Date.now()-new Date("$(twitch $(channel) "{{uptimeAt}}")").getTime())/3600000,
  toIndex=(d,l,u,c)=>d<l?0:d>=u?c-1:Math.floor((c-2)*(d-l)/(u-l))+1;
  messages[toIndex(hrs,1,5,5)]
)
```

To use it, you need to flatten it down to just one line by removing all the spaces:

```js
@$(channel) is $(eval let messages=["a-ok","irritated","wrathful","furious","in a fit of rage"],hrs=(Date.now()-new Date("$(twitch $(channel) "{{uptimeAt}}")").getTime())/3600000,toIndex=(d,l,u,c)=>d<l?0:d>=u?c-1:Math.floor((c-2)*(d-l)/(u-l))+1;messages[toIndex(hrs,1,5,5)])
```